# Child record Access in parent child relationship

Tags: apex

Can anyone tell me how to access the child records in parent child relationship?
My code snippet follows:

```
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account];   
for(Account  a: acc){    
     System.debug('CAaount name:'+ a.Name);   

//I don't know how to access contact s here       
for(Contact c:a.Contacts)     
{ System.debug('Conatct Last:' +c.LastName);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
List acc = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
for(Account a: acc){
    system.debug('Account name:'+ a.Name);

    List<Contact> Con = a.getSObjects('Contacts');
    for(Contact c:Con){ 
    system.debug('Contact Last:' +c.LastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too simplify very much..

```
for (Account a: acc)
{
    for (Contacts con : acc.Contacts)
    {
        //Anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and even simpler

```
for(Account  a: [select id, name, (select id, lastname from Contacts) from Account])
  for (Contact c: a:contacts) {
    system.debug(c.lastname + ' is a contact on ' + a.name);
  }
```